# How to Automate End to End Testing For Etherium Dapps With Metamask?

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, testing, truffle-test

I'm wondering what the best way to test the entire stack of a dapp is?

From UI -> to wallet connection -> web3.js and interacting with the smart contract?

In web2 we could just use something like [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), but [extensions can't run inside headless chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c5). So I'm not sure the best way to go about automating full workflows
with Metamask.

If there is a framework or service for this, I'd love to know, as I'd rather not roll my own solution as described [here](https://blog.neufund.org/how-not-to-lose-millions-of-dollars-in-your-ico-end-to-end-testing-for-dapps-f10b8becef7e)

If you have any suggestions I would love to hear them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem!

https://github.com/Synthetixio/synpress

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/69541)

Comment: Yes! I discovered synpress--very cool repo!

Answer (score 0):

You can test Metamask interactions with Synpress, e.g check if you can connect with the metamask wallet from your DApp with the following test case:

```
describe('Test User Login', () => {

    it('Connects with Metamask', () => {
       cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
        // find "Connect Wallet" button and click it
        cy.contains('Connect Wallet').click();
        // assuming there is only metamask popping up 
        // always important to switch between metamask and 
        // cypress window
        cy.switchToMetamaskWindow();
        // connect to dapp
        cy.acceptMetamaskAccess().should("be.true");
        cy.confirmMetamaskSignatureRequest();
        // switch back to cypress window (your dApp)
        cy.switchToCypressWindow();
        // check UI change
        cy.contains('...').should('be.visible');
    })
  })
```

For more details on how to use Synpress check this tutorial.

https://medium.com/coinmonks/test-e2e-login-to-dapp-with-metamask-with-synpress-5248dd1f17c1